# Find harmonic function vanishing on the boundary and with a specific bound

Tags: analysis, harmonic-functions, maximum-principle

Find all harmonic functions $u$ in a half-plane $H$ so that $u=0$ on $\partial H$ and $\vert u(x)\vert \le \vert x\vert$ in $H$.

This domain is not bounded. If it's bounded, then after using the maximum principe and the minimum principle, we conclude $u\equiv 0$ and the condition that $\vert u(x)\vert \le \vert x\vert$ will hold automatically.

I guess we should use the maximum principle for the unbounded case, but I don't remember the description of it and don't know how to process.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean for $u$ to be continuous on $\bar H?$

Comment: Yeah, $u$ is continuous on $\bar{H}$.